# how to search itunes with predefined search criteria (variable)

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, itunes

I was wondering if I have a song name and artist name as a variable in my app, is there a way when I click on a button (obviously have an event listener), I can open itunes with that song in the search bar being searched. I know in the past I've used 
`ti.open.platform(url)` 
to open websites but I'm not sure if there's a way to automatically search this on itunes. All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can use [`Titanium.Media.queryMusicLibrary`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-queryMusicLibrary).

For example:

```
var matches = Titanium.Media.queryMusicLibrary({title : your_variable});
```

On Android, you can do this using [Intents](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Intents).

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    type: "text/plain"
});

intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, 'song name or search term');
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Alternatively, use a module, [like this free one](https://github.com/liccowee/Ti.Media.MusicPlayer-for-Android).

Comment: thanks, I got it working for Android simply using: var SongVar="blondie maria";
playStoreSearch="http://play.google.com/store/search?q="+SongVar+"&c=music";  Titanium.Platform.openURL(playStoreSearch);
and for iOS with itunesSearch= "http://itunes.com/blondie/maria"; .